# javascript ajax is not sent alphabetic characters to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

in my javascript ajax code i send some data to another php files for record data to mysql database. 
when i use just numeric data it is record all data to mysql  (like this)

```
var myKeyVals = { pays: '123', order_id :'555' } 

var saveData = $.ajax({

  type: 'POST',
  url: "<?=$base_url?>pay/Paypal2.php",
  data: myKeyVals,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(resultData)
  {
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name+'--'+data.orderID)
  }
}
```

but when ı use alphabetic charecter in data , ajax script is not send data 
like this

```
 var myKeyVals = { pays: 'abc784', order_id :'ab45c' } 

 var saveData = $.ajax({

  type: 'POST',
  url: "<?=$base_url?>pay/Paypal2.php",
  data: myKeyVals,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(resultData)
  {
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name+'--'+data.orderID)
  }
}
```

my recorder pages php code is like this

```
      $x=$_POST['pays'];
      $y=$_POST['order_id'];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO table(pays, order_id) VALUES ($x, $y)";
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
      } 
      else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
      $conn->close();
```

Comment: Add an `error` key to the $.ajax function with a function that logs the error that comes in. Also, please post your php code, as the problem most likely lies over there

Comment: Your problem is called SQL injection bug, read the links to learn how to prevent that.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot A SQL error won't turn into an AJAX error unless he adds error checking code in PHP that makes it return an error HTTP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent some SQL Injection and resolve your problem, just use parameters

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table(pays, order_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
if(!$stmt) die('we have had some problem here');
$stmt->bindparam('s', $x); //replaces first ?
$stmt->bindparam('s', $y); //replaces second ?
$stmt->execute();
```

Also there some good practices you can apply, for example, if $y is numeric

```
$y=$_POST['order_id'];
if( !is_numeric($y) ) die('$y must be a numeric value');
```

Or if $y is a hash formed only by alfanumeric characters, you can also check for it

```
if( !preg_match("/[^a-z0-9]+$/i",$y) ) die('$y has other characters other than a-z0-9');
```